# How to bring Coordinator - AppBarLayout animation android 23

Tags: android

i completed Coordinator - AppBarLayout animation in android 22 version, but when i update buildToolsVersion to '23.0.3' and design support version com.android.support:design:23.1.0' it is not working,  please suggest me any work arround.

Here is my build.gradle with

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

targetSdkVersion 23

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

and i still use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

Comment: it is working in the sample project, when mapping same detail into original project it is not working

Comment: i checked everything, do you have any idea

Comment: can you add a pic what happening?

Comment: Am having toolbar that is static. below that, one header like view is there to show highlighted content. below that tab bar is there. immediate below one view pager with fragments that has list view. when scrolling up the list view ,header view and the tab bar also move to top, ie. header view will go beyond the toolbar and tab bar will be stayed below the toolbar, when scrolling down header view will come in to the screen. this what i want, this is working well in the sample, but not in the project.

Comment: unfortunately when scrolling up the list view nothing happen, only list view scrolling is hapening. NOTE when i click and scroll on the TABBAR and HEADER this view get animated as what i want.